# href error in .jsp

Tags: jsp

i had this code in my .jsp file:

```
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/client_home.jsp" id="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/client_about.jsp" id="about">About</a></li>
```

and when i click the link, i got this error:

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   File "/1920.14042009/pages/client_navbar.jsp" not found
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803) ...

i also tried replacing ${pageContext.request.contextPath}...
with

```
http://localhost:8080/1920.14042009/pages/client_about.jsp.
```

error still persists.

help pls...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the two lines of code or using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

The file `client_navbar.jsp` is not available in the context, but is referred by the jsp file that the link points to. Please check...

Comment: no, client_navbar.jsp exists..and even if i tried to comment the jsp include of it, error is still exists.

Comment: in this project, we've been using .jsp - java servlet - service - dao architechture..

Answer (score 0):

How this File "/1920.14042009/pages/client_navbar.jsp"  came into Picture, How it is redirected to this file, can you please post redirection code if any along with package structure.